# How does one decompress a compressed file (zip, bz2 etc), within Dropbox (without downloading to client first)?

Tags: dropbox

Say I have a compressed file (zip etc) stored in my dropbox account (in the cloud, not on my local device), is there a way to programmatically expand the file in my dropbox account, without downloading it locally first ?

- I do not want to download the file first. That defeats the purpose, since i can just upload the decompressed files in the first face.
- I've looked at various Dropbox api's, and while I can find a lot of information on how to put or remove files, I haven't found anything (yet) on how to decompress a file programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

No, Dropbox doesn't have this functionality.